# Is there a simpler solution for this recuurence?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

Consider this recurrence relation,
$$T(n)=T(n-\sqrt{n})+1$$
I try to show that $T(n)=O(\sqrt{n})$.

Also, I read [this link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131810/prove-upper-bound-of-the-recurrence-tn-tn-sqrtn1), but my question is, can I claim that, at each step  $n$ decreased by at least $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$ to reach $\frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: "at each step $n$ decreased...": what ??

Comment: At each step of our recurrence, $n$ decrased by at least $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$.

Comment: ??? In a step $n$ is constant ???

Comment: No, $n$ isn't constant. At the first step we have $n-\sqrt{n}$ at the next step we have $n-\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-\sqrt{n}}$. My question is, can we claim at each step we decrease $n$ by at least $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$?

Comment: If you are asking if $n-\sqrt n<n-\sqrt{\dfrac n2}$, the answer is yes. "$n$ decreases" is a language abuse.

Comment: I ask at  step $k$, can we claim that our remaining value is at least $n-k\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$?

Comment: $n-\sqrt n>n-k\sqrt{\dfrac n2}$ for $k\ge2$, obviously. But your description is pretty ambiguous and error prone. Better use $n_k$ then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the base case is $T(n)=1$ for $n\le 1$. If you accept the fact that $T(\cdot)$ is an increasing function, you can show by induction on $m \ge 1$ that $T(m^2) < 2m$.

If $m \le 1$ then the claim is trivially true. Assume now that the claim holds for $m \ge 1$. You have:
$$
\begin{align*}
T((m+1)^2) &\le T((m+1)^2 - (m+1)) + 1 =
T(m^2 + 2m +1 - m-1) +1 \\
&= T(m^2 + m) + 1
= T(m^2 + m -\sqrt{m^2+m})+2\\
&\le T(m^2)+2
< 2m+2=2(m+1).
\end{align*}
$$

Then $T(n) = O(\sqrt{n})$ follows by choosing $m = \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ since $T(n) \le T(m^2) < 2(m+1) < 2(\sqrt{n} +2) = O(\sqrt{n})$.